# Using .NET MVC Globalization is it possible to access resources from different projects within a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I have many different projects within a solution. I am in the process of localizing our website, but i have a question about how to access globalization resources from a project outside of our main web project. for example, i'm using a project to process twitter oauth tokens, and each language will have a different twitter account with it's own set of consumer_key and consumer_secret, so i would like to be able to put each language specific twitter application information inside of a localized file inside of Global_AppResources folder within my website project. but, my twitter oauth project, which is a separate project outside of website project needs a way to access this information. any ideas?

inside my twitter oauth project, what libraries do i need to reference so i can do something like this:

```
GetGlobalResourceObject("WebResources", "TwitterConsumerKey");
```

Instead of using a localized resource, i could put all the information inside of my web.config file, but each language will have its own set of information, which sort of defeats the purpose of bloating the web.config file. don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Satellite assemblies. Give [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70s77c20%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) a read.